# Converting HList to HMap[Int, TypeTag[_]] in shapeless

Tags: scala, shapeless

Lets assume the below code,

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import shapeless._

trait Base
case class A() extends Base
case class B() extends Base
case class C() extends Base

val tt = List(typeTag[A], typeTag[B], typeTag[C])

val tts = typeTag[A] :: typeTag[B] :: typeTag[C] :: HNil



cast(A(), tts.head) 
case(A(), tt.head) //res1: Product with Serializable with Base = A()


def cast[A](a: Base, tt: TypeTag[A]): A = a.asInstanceOf[A]
```

If you run the above code, you can see the difference in what the both cast returns.
Might sound naive, but with the first cast, I would access `case class A`s members, since it return type is just A, but wont be the case with normal list.

I do agree shapeless HList makes them possible, would it be possible to do the same with HMap?

example:
    val hmap = HMap(1 -> typeTag[A], 2 -> typeTag[B], 3 -> typeTag[C])

And when I try to do `hmap.get(1)`, it should return `TypeTag[A]` similar to how it would work if I do `tts.head`

Also, when I do `cast(A(), tts.head)` it runs fine, but when I do `cast(A(), tts(0))` it fails.

Both return signature in the worksheet looks identical

```
tts(0) //res2: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A] = 
       TypeTag[A$A151.this.A]

tts.head //res3: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A] = 
          TypeTag[A$A151.this.A]
```

Comment: Why `HMap` and not a record?

Comment: `HMap`s require additional types and implicits that specify allowed mapping. I should be able to explain why your example isn't working, given full code you use for `HMap`. Also, a use case for that machinery might be helpful.

Comment: My requirement is quite simple.I need a map and upon getting a value for a specific key, I want it to return the `TypeTag[A]` so that I could cast it.

Example: `hmap.get(1) // should return TypeTag[A]` like how it would for a HList when I do `hlist.head`

Comment: Can you provide your code for `HMap` which compiles but fails? Or you have never got it to work?